# Option[Int] as index in loop

Tags: scala, loops, scala-option

I am new at Scala so I do not know if I will ask something obvious.

I am currently trying to define a function which can or can not receive a parameter called "position". This parameter is an Int (in case the user decides to pass it). Otherwise, it should be considered as a "None" (because it will mean that nothing has been passed as parameter).
If it is a None, then: position = series.length - 1. I am trying to use Option here, since I do not want the user to pass a position if he does not require it.

```
def example(series: Vector[Double], position: Option[Int]): Vector[Double] = {
  position match {
    case Some(value) =>  value
    case None => series.length - 1
  }
  for (i <- position until series.length) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But when I try to use it in an loop as an Integer, it gives me an error (Type mismatch. Requiered: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, Int, NotInferedCol[Int]]. Found: Int).

I have been trying different things to make this "position" as an optional value, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `i <- position.getOrElse(series.length -1) until series.length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your code is that this:

```
position match {
  case Some(value) =>  value
  case None => series.length - 1
}
```

is an expression that doesn't mutate the value of `position`, which is probably what you may have assumed.

You have to bind the value produced by the expression to use it in the code underneath it:

```
val positionWithDefault =
  position match {
    case Some(value) => value
    case None => series.length - 1
  }
for (i <- positionWithDefault until series.length) {
  ...
}
```

Furthermore, as noted in a comment, the behavior of the `match` expression is the same you'd get out of `getOrElse`

```
for (i <- position.getOrElse(series.length - 1) until series.length) {
  ...
}
```